# ¿Que diferencia hay entre usar un validador de campos o validar el modelo mediante clean?

Tags: python, django

Suponiendo que tengo un modelo Django como el siguiente:

```
class Comprobante(models.Model):
    punto_venta = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

Y quiero validar el modelo y particularmente que `punto_venta` sea un valor de 1 a 9999. Entiendo que hay dos formas:

#### Usar un validador en el campo

```
def punto_venta_validate(value):
    if not value:
        raise ValidationError(_('El punto de venta es obligatorio'))
    if value <1 or value > 9999:
        raise ValidationError(_('El punto de venta debe debe ser un valor entre 1 y 9999'))

class Comprobante(models.Model):
    punto_venta = models.IntegerField(blank=True, validators=[punto_venta_validate]))
```

#### Validar en el evento `clean()` del modelo

```
def clean(self):
    punto_venta_validate(self.punto_venta)
```

La única diferencia visible es que un `ValidationError` cuando se valida el campo mediante el uso de `validators`, mostrará el mensaje al lado del campo en la interfaz de administración, cuando usamos `clean()` para validar, veo que el error aparece sobre todos los campos. Eventualmente con `clean()` también podríamos validar múltiples condiciones y cada error agregarlo a una lista, de esta forma podríamos mostrar todos los errores de cada campo, por lo que tampoco sería una diferencia entre ambos métodos. Entonces: **¿Cual es la diferencia entre ambos métodos?¿es solo un tema de como se muestran los `ValidationError` o hay algo más que se me está escapando?**

Comment: Los validadores solo validan, no devuelven el formato mejorado; Los métodos limpios validan y devuelven un valor (a veces modificado).

Comment: @J.Rodríguez, lo que dices es que con un validador no podríamos modificar el valor del campo (por ejemplo para corregirlo) y con el metódo `clean()` eventualmente sí. Es una buena diferencia, si quieres hacerla respuesta.. sin duda lo es. Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efectivamente como te menciono en el comentario:

- Los `validadores` solo validan la entrada, no devuelven el formato mejorado, es decir no se puede modificar. Si la entrada no es válida, solo generará un [`ValidationError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ValidationError).
- Los métodos `Clean()` validan y devuelven un valor que podría ser un valor ligeramente modificado según los requisitos.

> Un **validador** es simplemente un objeto o función invocable que toma un valor y simplemente no devuelve nada si el valor es válido o genera un `ValidationError` si no es así. (Esto lo encuentra en la documentación: [Aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators)) 
>    El valor de retorno simplemente se ignora.
>
> Si desea poder modificar el valor, puede usar el `clean_` campo, en los formularios como se describe [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Django primero ejecutará los validadores de campo incorporados (por defecto), luego sus validadores de campo personalizados (usando `validators=[su_validador]` en sus modelos). Entonces, Django ejecutará los métodos `clean()` y `clean<campo>()`.

Creo que una de las principales diferencia entre los métodos `validator` y un `clean_<campo>()` es que este último solo está destinado a formularios. Y el `validator` se puede usar tanto para sus formularios como para sus modelos (y, por lo tanto, también se usará, por ejemplo en la interfaz de administración).

Además, anular el método `clean_<campo>()` es la forma recomendada de validar datos contra elementos en su base de datos.

**Nota:** También puedes aplicar el mismo validador a tus campos de formulario si solo lo quieres allí y no en toda tu aplicación.

> Aquí hay una documentación interesante sobre Validación (Traducir del Ingles):
>
> - [Validación de formulario y campo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).
> - [Validadores](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/).